# Вывод счетчика цикла через AJAX

Tags: ajax, php

Есть count.php файл с циклом:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    // Тут действие номер $i
    echo json_encode(array('id' => $i));
}
```

И сам javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/count.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
            $(".main").text(data.id);
            }
            });
        },1000);
    });
</script>
```

Задача: вывести на экран через AJAX счетчик цикла.

При решении задачи, возникла сложность получения данных. Пока выполняется цикл, файл не доступен.

Comment: и что было сделано?
Где ajax где js?

Сейчас сезон отпусков, и как обычно первыми идут в них экстрасенсы, они бы и рады помочь, но они в отпуске, а мы смертные так не можем решать проблемы и задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно вывести сразу все числа или по очереди?

если сразу все то тогда

изменить вывод

```
$arr=array();
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $arr[$i]=$i;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

тогда выдаст весь массив. ну и немного переделать вывод в JS

Comment: Немного исправил код. В цикле выполняется некоторое действие.
Мне нужно вывести на экран номер этого действия. К примеру, $i = 1, на экране "Действие № 1", $i = 2, на экране "Действие № 2" и тд.

Comment: Вопрос тогда, зачем делать в цикле то что нужно в данный момент.

я имею ввиду, ну если нужно получать данные по каким-то действиям, отправляй тогда на каждое действие запрос, а сервак тебе на него отдаст ответ.

Просто в данном случае не вижу смысла делать что-то в цикле и постоянно это выводить. это все проскочит настолько быстро что вообще бессмысленно.

скрипт JS получит первый вывод и на этом он закончит обращаться к серваку, хотя тот упорно будет продолжать выполнять что-то.

Comment: Проблема в том, что пока не отработает цикл, я не могу получить ответа от сервера.
К примеру, в цикле я загружаю файлы. Мне нужно знать, какой файл загружается в данный момент.

Comment: Так загружай файлы изначально по одному в цикле JS а от скрипта получай данные. Скармливай ему по одному файлу и по одному запросу.